# Changing the value of a static member object

Tags: java, c++

Coming from Java, I have learned certain ways to do things which somewhat apply to C++, but it seems not entirely. In Java, I could use

```
class A {
    public static A instance;
    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}

class B {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A.instance = new A();
        A.instance.foo();
    }
}
```

But in C++, this seems either impossible or somehow much different. Here's what I thought would achieve the same effect in C++:

```
class A {
    public:
        static A instance;
        void foo();
};

void A::foo() {
    cout << "Hello, world!";
}

int main() {
    A::instance();
    A::instance.foo();
}
```

But this yields "error: no match for call" at `A::instance()`. In the actual code, the constructor has parameters, if that makes a difference. I have heard that a static member has to be initialized at the very start of the program, but the instance can only be created once I have some information about the object that it will store. How do I correctly set this value once I have all the required information?

Comment: instance is an object, not a callable method.  Did you mean to make an instance metthod:  A & instance() { static A myinstance; return myinstance;}?

Comment: You are calling `A::instance();` as a function, while it clearly isn't.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius this is the only way I have seen an object initialized (`A obj(3, "hi");`). I know it's not a function, but my will is to set the value of it inside that method.

Answer (score 4):

You must define the A instance:

```
class A {
    public:
        static A instance;
        void foo();
};

// call the constructor here, the compiler will know what to do with it.
A A::instance = A();

void A::foo() {
    cout << "Hello, world!";
}

int main() {
    A::instance.foo();
}
```

Comment: In the real program, I don't have all the information needed to call the constructor before I've done other stuff in the constructor. This is why I want to set the value inside `main()`.

Comment: @SamM That's the thing - you can't initialize static variables from outside of global scope (i.e. from within functions).

Comment: @SamM You have a dependency problem that needs solving first. Remember that variables of a class type in C++ hold the actual object, not some kind of (potential) reference to one.

Answer (score 3):

'instance' is a variable. You need to initialize it outside main function.
This should work:

```
class A {
public:
    static A instance;
    void foo();
};

void A::foo() {
    cout << "Hello, world!";
}

A A::instance;

int main() {
    A::instance.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your comments have clarified that you want to construct `instance` after you have entered `main`.  In that case, you need to make `instance` be a (smart) pointer, and not an actual object.  So:

```
class A {
    public:
        static std::unique_ptr<A> instance;
        void foo();
};

// Construct the pointer object.
A A::instance = {};

void A::foo() {
    cout << "Hello, world!";
}

int main() {
    A::instance = std::make_unique<A>();  // Arguments here.
    A::instance->foo();     // Use -> not .
}
```